# Is it possible to change out an image src="" before the original image loads

Tags: javascript, performance

I've been looking at Javascript that can change the src of an image. I'm simply wondering if this can be done before the browser attempts to fetch the original image.

Example.

```
Src="Large-Image"
```

Can I (with javascript, I would imagine.. node.JS maybe?) serve the user `src="smaller-image"`?

Obviously, there would be no performance gain if the browser loads the large image first.

Comment: I'm confused - you mention node.js here, but in a comment on an answer you say "a server side solution is out of the question", which would exclude node.js.  This seems to have a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to it... what is the core problem that you are trying to solve with the solution you are asking about here?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so, JS needs the image-tag to be available to access the attributes, so it has to execute later than that (Like on a documentReady or by being placed after the  tag), but at that point the browser has already started downloading the image.

However, I have seen solutions where you don't set the url on the "src" attribute, but on another attribute name, like "data-src". Your Javascript can dynamically set that url to the "src" attribute to prompt the browser to start downloading.

For example (assuming jQuery is loaded):

```
<img data-src="http://www.url.nl/image.png" />

<script>
    $("img").each(function (index, element) {
       var $element = $(element);
       var imageUrl = $element.attr("data-src");

       //Do your checks here to change the image-url to a smaller one when required

       $element.attr("src", imageUrl);
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I'm trying to avoid using data-src, but if thats the only way..

Comment: Not sure if it's the only way, but I've seen it used in some MVVM frameworks, I think. A better way would be a server-side solution, ofcourse.

Comment: Yeh, I'm trying to create an unintrusive way of increasing performance on a website. As such, a server side solution is out of the question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am a little late to the party... But yeah, of course you can!

The trick is to do EXACTLY what everyone warns you "not to do" and reference your `JS` file in the `<head>` section of your webpage. This way, your `JavaScript` loads before anything else.

Then use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {...});` to grab your image element, as soon as the DOM is available (but before the image file is loaded).

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="original_image_URL">
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is `main.js` which goes with it:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('img').src = 'new_image_URL';
});
```

Have fun!

Comment: This answer was worth waiting 8 years. Thanks! 
Unfortunately I can't accept it until I validate it and, as you might've guessed, I'm not working on this anymore. 

I'll be sure the accept the moment I validate that this works.

Comment: Hey, no worries - sorry I didn't see your question sooner! Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, not overly elegant by any means. Call your function to change the image's source with the onload event.

```
<img id="YourID" src="PathToFirstImage" onload="YourFunction()">
```

Though this changes the image after it has loaded as long as the viewing browser isn't going insanely slow your audience should never even see the original image.

Comment: It's about performance, not perception, so this is no good for me unfortunately.

Comment: So it is about server performance, not browser user-experience then?

Comment: That's a pretty sweet idea. I could see something like `<img src="pending.png?url=assets/images/graphic.png&v=1.2.1" />` being pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand jquery ready function correctly, [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), you should be able to achive what you want.

"The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code"

On the other hand [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), says

"In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead."

So according to the docs ready is called before images are loaded, but if you can block downloading and change image paths can only a test answer.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you, I will look into this. Generally, I wouldn't expect increased performance from a script that effectively stops loading a page, but if it's possible to change out the images quick enough, it could work

Comment: I know that jQuery is very over used these days, but IIRC ready() is one of those areas where there is quite a bit of difference between the browsers so using jQuery makes sense. Also it is rare these days to see a system fall gracefully when javascript is not present. Kudos for thinking about it and making an effort.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to do it but not reliably and you can't leave the `src` blank if you want to output valid markup so would probably hurt mobile performance more than it helps.

Rather than reinvent the wheel there are a number of client and server side ways to do it that don't rely on JS (which you cannot guarantee will be enabled).  All of them would be more reliable and are standards compliant (CSS media targeting for example) which would give you better results.

Comment: I wouldn't wish to leave the src blank, as this would be my key for finding the replacement. So if JS doesn't fire off in time (or at all) the original image would load as usual... 

I "may be able to do it", would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Perhaps I was being too subtle.  You're trying to do something in a way that is at best unreliable, when reliable methods exist and you should use them instead.

Comment: So you won't be able to elaborate for me?